# Chinese Restaurant Process implementation in Python

Tags: python, random, distribution, sampling

I have wrote a code in Python for CRP problem. The problem itself can be found here:
http://cog.brown.edu/~mj/classes/cg168/slides/ChineseRestaurants.pdf

And to give a short description of it:
Suppose we want to assign people entering to a restaurants to potentially infinite number of tables. If $z_i$ represents the random variable assigned for the $i$'th person entering the restaurant the following should hold:

With probability $p(z_i=a|z_1,...,z_{i-1})=\frac{n_a}{i-1+\alpha} for $n_a>0$, $i$'th person will sit in table $a$ and with probability $p(z_i=a|z_1,...,z_{i-1})=\frac{\alpha}{i-1+\alpha} $i$'th person will sit around a new table.

I am not quite sure if my code is correct cause I am surprised how small the final number of tables are.

I would be happy if somebody could say if the implementation is correct and if so are there any possible improvements.

```
import numpy as np
def CRP(alpha,N):
    """Chinese Restaurant Process with alpha as concentration parameter and N 
    the number of sample"""
    #Array which will save for each i, the number of people people sitting
    #until table i
    summed=np.ones(1) #first person assigned to the first table
    for i in range(1,N):
        #A loop that assigns the people to tables

        #randind represent the random number from the interval [1,i-1+alpha]
        randind=(float(i)+alpha)*np.random.uniform(low=0.0, high=1.0, size=1)
        #update is the index for the table that the person should be placed which
        #if greater than the total number, will be placed in a new table
        update=np.searchsorted(summed,randind,side='left')
        if randind>i:
            summed=np.append(summed,i+1)
        else:
            zerovec=np.zeros(update)
            onevec=np.ones(summed.size-update)
            summed+=np.append(zerovec,onevec)
    #This part converts summed array to tables array which indicates the number
    #of persons assigned to that table
    tables=np.zeros(summed.size)
    tables[0]=summed[0]
    for i in range(1,summed.size):
        tables[i]=summed[i]-summed[i-1]
    return tables
a=CRP(0.9999,1000)
print a
```

Comment: This should be on http://codereview.stackexchange.com/ but no option to migrate it.

Comment: @InbarRose, the number of branches of stackexchange increases by day, and it is really funny to get minus vote because of being unaware of a new branch!

Comment: You might have gotten a down vote because this "question" serves no use to anyone else except for you. Any answers to this question will only affect this particular instance at this particular time. It does not fit with the way questions should be asked on this site, but is perfect for the codereview site.

Comment: @InbarRose, Seriously?? 
Well for your information, "Chinese Restaurant Process" is considered to be one of the new useful sampling methods in modern statistics and if you Google it up, you'll figure out that there is no useful python implementation of it! I am pretty sure people would be very happy to get a correct(reviewed by people here) implementation of it!

Comment: This is not a code distribution site. You can try github, I hear that is a great place for distributing Python snippets. StackOverflow is not here to review your code, or to distribute your code, it is here to help you with problem you may be having with your code. If you have a specific problem with your code, you are welcome to re-word your question, and improve it by adding samples, expected outcomes, and by singling out the parts of code that need help.

Comment: How are we supposed to say something is correct if we don't know what its supposed to do?

Comment: If I was sure this code is correct I wouldn't have ask this question and as you suggested would have put it on some website like github. I already mentioned my problem :"I am not quite sure if my code is correct cause I am surprised how small the final number of tables are."

Comment: @GamesBrainiac, added it up

Comment: @Naji: http://codereview.stackexchange.com is not new - it's been around for nearly three years !

Comment: @PaulR, I wasn't trying to say that its new. I was trying to say that the subdomains of stackexchange are a lot. Being not aware of one, should not result in downvote but a flag or suggestion!

Comment: @Naji: don't worry about the down-votes - they just reflect the fact that your question has been posted on an inappropriate board - your reputation will be restored once the question has been migrated to somewhere more appropriate.

Answer (score 1):

Suggestion. Forget about the code you have written. Construct declarative tests of the code. By taking that approach, you start with examples for which you know the correct answer. That would have answered Brainiac's question, for example.

Then write your program. You will likely find that if you start approaching problems this way, you may create sub-problems first, for which you can also write tests. Until they all pass, there is no need to rush on to the full problem.

Comment: I am not quite sure if I understood what you are implying but I am not familiar with writing test samples for a stochastic program?

Comment: For starters, what do you expect if N = -1, 0, 1? How about alpha < 0, = 0, etc.

You assert something about the state of the system using CRP (alpha, N) under combinations of those conditions. If there are cases with analytically determinable results, test them. Might as well find the bugs before you start using it.

Comment: I actually got the answer here:
http://stats.stackexchange.com/questions/72961/cumulants-in-chinese-restaurant-process

I asked for the cumulants.

Comment: As to testing a stochastic algorithm, you can use an interface for which you supply a stochastic result as here when using it in production, but during testing you supply pre-determined values for which you can calculate your results in advance. If your system has asymptotic behavior then you can also test that it approaches that behavior.